# Pandas: convert object to Date Time, removing exceptions

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, try-except, date-conversion

I am trying to convert an Object to a Date Time variable. However, some dates are outside the time range. How could I fix it with a `try..except` construct, removing exceptions outside time range?

```
df['Date_Time'] = df['Date_Time'].astype('datetime64[ns]')
```

Error:

```
ValueError: year 60521 is out of range
```

I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
try:
    df['Date_Time'] = df['Date_Time'].astype('datetime64[ns]')
except:
    pass
```

Sample input:

```
0          2020-09-08 23:59:41
1          2020-09-08 23:58:07
2          2020-09-08 23:59:42
```

Comment: Can you please share sample input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the `errors` parameter of the `to_datetime` function.

```
df['Date_Time'] = pandas.to_datetime(df['Date_Time'], errors='coerce')
```

any errors in conversion will be set as `NaT`