# Remove rows with invalid date and time data

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime

below is my sample dataframe.

[image]

I need to remove the columns that have an invalid date or time.  Therefore rows 3,5,6 should be deleted. I need a way to verify if the date & time columns contain valid date & times.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67516396/202229). Try to convert the date and time columns respectively, catch exceptions or coerce them.

Comment: Please, avoid [posting images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text). It is a better practice to transcribe them instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you could use `to_datetime` method with `errors=coerce` parameter; then use `notna` to create a boolean mask to filter `df` with:

```
df = df[pd.to_datetime(df['time'], errors='coerce').notna()]
```

Comment: enke: good answer, but the question is a duplicate. Best to post your answer on [Pandas: convert object to Date Time, removing exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67516252/pandas-convert-object-to-date-time-removing-exceptions) so we can upvote it there. Feel free to add extra sample input that that OP didn't, to show the different ways in which a string could be an invalid date.